# null is not an object in React native Native interfaces

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I've installed different npm packages which would help me launch the camera or get pictures from the phone. I installed them in my react native project, run `pod install` and also run `npx react-native link`. Even though I did that, it still shows me that null is not an object when trying to work with the native interface.

I'm a bit lost. Just uploading an image should be something somehow simple for an app. I opened the app with `yarn start`. When trying `yarn ios` (`react-native run-ios`) it shows me an error:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it
> exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider
> building your app with Xcode.app

I can add more logs, code or something else if needed. My version 0.63.3 and moved to 0.67 and still does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @IbadUrRehman no

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to link libraries for RN. It may cause errors for latest versions of RN. Please try the following:

1. Unlink libraries
2. remove node modules and pods
3. run npm install and pods install
   That should be it.

PS also check the library docs - there may be some additional setup to do, but I think the 3 steps above will help